# How to count rows on joined table

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have 2 tables --  a master (called groups) and details (called users)

I want to return each and every master row for subsequent display, but I only want to count how many detail rows match the master

My query is not working properly -- it only returns the first row in the master table

```
$query_string = '
    SELECT groups.userGroupID, userGroup,
           count(users.userGroupID) AS howMany
    FROM groups_table AS groups
    JOIN users_table AS users ON users.userGroupID = groups.userGroupID
    ORDER BY groups.userGroupID
';
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: you need a `group by groups.userGroupID`.

Comment: thanks @MarcB -- that returned the first 2 master rows only

Comment: you didn't specify a join type either, so by default mysql's doing an inner join, and showing rows which have records on BOTH sides of the join only. if you want all the groups, even if they have no users, then use a LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Forgot your group by:

```
SELECT groups.userGroupID, userGroup,
       count(users.userGroupID) AS howMany
FROM groups_table AS groups
LEFT JOIN users_table AS users ON users.userGroupID = groups.userGroupID
GROUP BY groups.userGroupID
ORDER BY groups.userGroupID
```

Comment: do I need left join or right join because I am only getting 2 master rows

Comment: Left join if you want groups even if they have no users.

Comment: can't accept answer for 9 minutes (it's the one thing I truly hate about SO!) ... moving on -- I'll accept next time I log back on

Answer (score -1):

This works for me, hope it helps anyone else looking for same answer

```
SELECT COUNT(howMany) AS fo2
FROM(
 SELECT groups.userGroupID, userGroup,
 users.userGroupID AS howMany
 FROM groups_table AS groups
 JOIN users_table AS users ON users.userGroupID = groups.userGroupID
 ORDER BY groups.userGroupID) AS myCount
```